# How to uniquely identify computers that access a website

Tags: cookies, browser

I have to uniquely identify computers that access my website. The only solution i found so far is storing an id in a cookie or something similar to identify the browser but my problem is that you could copy the cookies and use them in another browser. is there any way to detect if the cookie is copied or some better way to identify the computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reliable way to uniquely identify a browser, because there is nothing that prevents two computers from having the exact same configurations (operation system, browser, location, cookies, flash configuration, etc).

The best that we can do is to gather as many information about the browser as possible. This is well-known approach called browser/device fingerprinting. Although the result is not perfect, it is quite good. Browser's fingerprint typically includes browser name, operating system, fonts, plugins installed, etc. You can test how unique your browser is using https://panopticlick.eff.org/.

Comment: how do i get the information which plugins are installed? i tried document.write(JSON.stringify(navigator.plugins)); but that doesn't return anything

Comment: Some browser restricts JavaScript code from iterating over the plugins, but you can still check whether certain plugins are installed. For example, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorPlugins.plugins.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has an array called $_Server which is an associative array with information such as the visitors IP which can be used in conjunction with cookies. JavaScript also offers the "navigator" object which contains information about the browser. You can save that information to a cookie and if it doesn't match with the browser they use on the next visit, it would indicate they are not using the same browser.

Comment: but the ip changes too often

Comment: Edited to offer additional methods.